# Any idea why the file is not compressed when using YUI Compressor from Java code instead of running it from command line?

Tags: java, yui-compressor

I use the following code to compress a CSS file using YUI Compressor but the CSS file dos not get compressed, it remains untouched. Any ideea why?

```
final InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(fileCss), "UTF-8");
final CssCompressor     cssCompressor     = new CssCompressor(inputStreamReader);

inputStreamReader.close();

final OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(fileCss), "UTF-8");
final Integer            cssParamLineBreak  = -1;

cssCompressor.compress(outputStreamWriter, cssParamLineBreak);
outputStreamWriter.close();
```

Where fileCss is a File object coming from a loop trough `FileUtils.listFiles`

yuicompressor-2.4.8

**LE:** They do read the file in the constructor. See https://github.com/yui/yuicompressor/blob/master/src/com/yahoo/platform/yui/compressor/CssCompressor.java#L25

I wrote the code based on https://github.com/yui/yuicompressor/blob/master/src/com/yahoo/platform/yui/compressor/YUICompressor.java#L20 which works when you call the jar from the command line. And they are doing the same thing as in closing the input stream after initializing the compressor.

And from command line it works if you have the same input file as the output one.

Comment: Have you tried writing to a different file? Using the same file for both input and output is non-ideal, IMO. I wouldn't close the input until you've finished the compression - I wouldn't be surprised if it only read the data when you call `compress`, rather than in the constructor.